# Reports combination of 3 objects

Tags: reporting

Here for Account i have 2 master-detailed relation objects X and Y, can i create a report by the combination of **3 objects**.

Relationships:
Account - master-detailed relation - X
Account - master-detailed relation - Y

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new custom report type.
[How to create custom report type.](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm)
In Step 1 make sure you check Deployment Status to deployed.
In Step 2 define Report Records Set, add the relations.

After creating report type you can add new report of this type.

Thanks